# Searching an image using ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have created an `ImageView` and is there any way to search for an image using google search? I want to search for an image and post it in the `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Custom search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/libraries) which is free and includes Google image search API too. 
then get images from API using some libraries like Volley or Retrofit and ... and use bitmap decoding operations and set too imageView.
[Here is](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) a good tutorial to how to parse API using volley.